# Axios + Symfony : Retrieve image path in response after submit

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, axios

trying to retrieve image path of uploaded media via `Axios` with `Symfony` backend.
So far the upload works fine : I can see the updated image after refreshing the page.
But in my JS response the object `Qrcode_image` is an empty array, and I can't find the path of the image to update my markup

JS

```js
UpdateQrcodeImage(){

    $("#website-qrcode-image-form").on("submit", function(event, datas) {

        event.preventDefault();
        
        const file = $('#website-qrcode-image')[0].files[0];
        const website_id = $("#website-id").attr('data-value');

        let fDatas = new FormData();
        fDatas.append('website-qrcodeimage', file);
        fDatas.append('website-id', website_id);

        const sendPostRequest = async () => {
            try {
                const resp = await axios.post(`/api/website/${website_id}/qrcode_image`, fDatas, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } });
                console.log(resp.data);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        };
        sendPostRequest();

    });
}
```

Controller: */src/Controller/Api/ApiWebsiteController.php*

```php
#[Route('/api/website/{id}/qrcode_image', name: 'api.website.qrcode_image', methods: ['POST', 'GET'])]
public function website_qrcode_image(?Website $website, Request $request): JsonResponse {

    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $file = $request->files->get('website-qrcodeimage');

    $media = new Media();
    $media->setMediaFile($file);
    $this->em->persist($media);
    $website->setQrcodeImage($media);
    $this->em->persist($website);
    $this->em->flush();

    return $this->json($website, 200, ['Content-Type' => "application/json"], ['groups' => ['qrcode']]);
}
```

Entity: */src/Entity/Website.php*

```php
    #[Groups(['qrcode'])]
    #[ORM\OneToOne(cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private ?Media $Qrcode_image = null;

    [...]

    public function getQrcodeImage(): ?Media
    {
        return $this->Qrcode_image;
    }

    public function setQrcodeImage(?Media $Qrcode_image): self
    {
        $this->Qrcode_image = $Qrcode_image;

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: You can return the path of the image and use it to show the image without refresh the page